# How do I (beautifully) extract this part of code to a subclass?

Tags: java, optimization

I have thought a lot about this but can't come to a proper solution. Also, it's hard to google things like this.

Note: The code itself is irrelevant, it's about how to do such a thing in general.

I have a class named `Creature` which has the following method:

```
private void move(int direction, LyxCamera camera, MapLayers mapLayers, ArrayList<Creature> entities) {
    if (!moving) {
        if (direction != NONE) {
            this.direction = direction;

            int goalGridPosX = gridPosX;
            int goalGridPosY = gridPosY;

            if (direction == UP) {
                goalGridPosY = gridPosY + 1;
            } else if (direction == RIGHT) {
                goalGridPosX = gridPosX + 1;
            } else if (direction == DOWN) {
                goalGridPosY = gridPosY - 1;
            } else if (direction == LEFT) {
                goalGridPosX = gridPosX - 1;
            }

            if (goalIsFree(goalGridPosX, goalGridPosY, mapLayers, entities)) {
                stop();
                moving = true;

                /* FROM HERE

                if (direction == UP) {
                    if (goalGridPosY > camera.getGridPosY() + 4) {
                        camera.move(direction, speed);
                    }
                } else if (direction == RIGHT) {
                    if (goalGridPosX > camera.getGridPosX() + 8) {
                        camera.move(direction, speed);
                    }
                } else if (direction == DOWN) {
                    if (goalGridPosY < camera.getGridPosY() + 4) {
                        camera.move(direction, speed);
                    }
                } else if (direction == LEFT) {
                    if (goalGridPosX < camera.getGridPosX() + 7) {
                        camera.move(direction, speed);
                    }
                }

                TO HERE*/

                gridPosX = goalGridPosX;
                gridPosY = goalGridPosY;

                step();
            }
        }
    }
```

I marked the code I want to extract to a subclass with "FROM HERE TO HERE".

I could place the code in a method and call the empty method, then overwrite the method in the subclass. But that really doesn't seem to be a proper solution. I could also copy the whole method and just remove the marked area in the superclass. This also doesn't seem to be best practice.

I'm sure you guys know exactly what I'm looking for. Oh, and if you have general suggestions to improve the code, feel free to let me know!

Maybe I'm just too tired already, and a solution will come to me in my dreams. Anyways, I'm very curious to see your suggestions!

Many thanks!

Regards Lyxodius

EDIT:

First, I'm very thankful that you guys took the time to give me answers so detailed!
My solution was inspired by all of your answers from here and stackexchange!

**Superclass "Creature.java":**

```
private void move(int direction, LyxCamera camera, MapLayers mapLayers,
        ArrayList<Creature> entities) {
    if (!moving && direction != NONE) {
        this.direction = direction;

        int goalGridPosX = gridPosX;
        int goalGridPosY = gridPosY;

        switch (direction) {
        case UP:
            goalGridPosY++;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            goalGridPosX++;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            goalGridPosY--;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            goalGridPosX--;
            break;
        }

        if (goalIsFree(goalGridPosX, goalGridPosY, mapLayers, entities)) {
            prepareMoving(goalGridPosX, goalGridPosY);
        }
    }
}

protected void prepareMoving(int goalGridPosX, int goalGridPosY) {
    startMoving(goalGridPosX, goalGridPosY);
}

private void startMoving(int goalGridPosX, int goalGridPosY) {
    stop();

    moving = true;

    gridPosX = goalGridPosX;
    gridPosY = goalGridPosY;

    step();
}
```

**Subclass "Player.java":**

```
@Override
protected void prepareMoving(int goalGridPosX, int goalGridPosY) {
    super.prepareMoving(goalGridPosX, goalGridPosY);
    moveCamera();
}

private void moveCamera() {
    if (direction == UP
            && gridPosY > camera.getGridPosY() + MINIMUM_VERTICAL_OFFSET) {
        camera.move(direction, speed);
    } else if (direction == RIGHT
            && gridPosX > camera.getGridPosX()
                    + MINIMUM_HORIZONTAL_OFFSET_RIGHT) {
        camera.move(direction, speed);
    } else if (direction == DOWN
            && gridPosY < camera.getGridPosY() + MINIMUM_VERTICAL_OFFSET) {
        camera.move(direction, speed);
    } else if (direction == LEFT
            && gridPosX < camera.getGridPosX()
                    + MINIMUM_HORIZONTAL_OFFSET_LEFT) {
        camera.move(direction, speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: For working code which you want opinions on, post on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). This StackOverflow is for questions about specific problems, not design opinions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple answer, you could just have a moveCamera protected method in the base class and call it from here.

To dig little deeper:

- What do you think the base class could represent? This class
  represents a Creature. Would the base class be a 'GameObject'?
- Also, could the moveCamera method instead be moved to the Camera
  object as a *move* method?

Best way to think about class is what real object it represents. The logic related to each object should be part of that class. The (+4) (+8) etc. movements that you are doing look like they should be part of the camera class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I posted my solution in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a perfect example of a use for an abstract class.  An abstract class should be used when you *know* some of the functionality.

```
public abstract class Creature{

    private void move(int direction, LyxCamera camera, MapLayers mapLayers,    
        ArrayList<Creature> entities) {
        if (!moving) {
            if (direction != NONE) {
                this.direction = direction;

                int goalGridPosX = gridPosX;
                int goalGridPosY = gridPosY;

                if (direction == UP) {
                    goalGridPosY = gridPosY + 1;
                } else if (direction == RIGHT) {
                    goalGridPosX = gridPosX + 1;
                } else if (direction == DOWN) {
                    goalGridPosY = gridPosY - 1;
                } else if (direction == LEFT) {
                    goalGridPosX = gridPosX - 1;
                }

                if (goalIsFree(goalGridPosX, goalGridPosY, mapLayers, 
                    entities)) {

                    stop();
                    moving = true;

                    // call the abstract method to be defined later 
                    //   (in sub classes)
                    doSomething(direction, goalGridPosX, goalGridPosY, 
                        camera);

                    gridPosX = goalGridPosX;
                    gridPosY = goalGridPosY;

                    step();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract void doSomething(final int direction, 
        final int goalGridPosX, final int goalGridPosY, 
        final LyxCamera camera);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The problem is that I also want to use what you defined as the abstract class as a not abstract class, I only want to have the subclass have extra functionality.
I posted my solution in the OP.